# Add DLQ after initial SQS queue has been deployed via Terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-sqs

I already have an SQS queue running in AWS which is receiving messages that was deployed without a DLQ or redrive policy. I now want to add a DLQ and redrive policy to this existing queue, but doing so gives me the following error.

> QueueAlreadyExists: A queue already exists with the same name and a different value for attribute RedrivePolicy

Is there no way to add this DLQ after the SQS queue has been deployed?

Comment: What does your terraform look like? Are you storing your terraform state in s3?

Comment: @razki Yes it's being stored in s3. I should mention if I name this differently and deploy it works just fine, so I think the terraform itself is fine, it's just the fact there's an existing SQS queue. Let me know if you still want to see a part of it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all your relevant Terraform code and also an example directory structure if they're not in the same place please? It might be worth looking at the [mcve] guide here to help structure your question more clearly.

Comment: @Josh Did you ever find a solution/workaround?

Comment: @zhanga I don't remember exactly but I believe destroying what you've already deployed and then deploying again would work

Comment: @Josh That does indeed work. Thanks.